# Installing MySQL extension in Godaddy Servers.

Tags: php, mysql, php-extension

I am not a Pro at server side scripting so here goes one small problem I am having and hopefully someone out there will be able to point me in the right direction.

I am transferring a site to a new shared hosting in Godaddy. In the process installatron didn't migrate correctly so I had to pick up where it left off and manually did the rest. After checking the PHP info I noticed that the MySQL Extension is not installed.

I did some research online and came up with this code to create an installation of the extension. My only problem is that I do not know where to add this code.

```
# apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

Do I add it to my php.ini file? do I input this through my cmd prompt? or Do I add it to my htaccess file?

I thought the CMD was the proper way to go but I don't mess around with CMD too often so I am slowly getting better at it.

Is this the proper way to go?

Do I use the same credentials to log in via CMD as FTP, cPanel or ???

Thank you for your constructive inputs.

Comment: `apt-get` is a command line program, to run that you need to SSH in to your server and type it in. However, I'm pretty sure you don't need to do this. I'd also be stunned that the MySQL extension isn't enabled by default.

Comment: I loaded a file called info.php and added the code phpinfo() to see if it was installed by default and I did not see a segment in the list labelled MySQL so I take it this means it is not installed right? I will go into the CMD and follow through with the rest. Thank you so much for the feedback. If I run into any hurdles I will come back here to see if you would be able to help any further.

Comment: It's unlikely that you will be allowed to install anything if it's a shared server, you may find the extension is already there but not included in the `php.ini` file.

Comment: ok then is the best solution to add something specific to the php.ini file instead? Because I do have access to one in the shared hosting. And what would be the best solution to take in this file? Adding some code or making some code already there accessible to the server?

Comment: Search the `php.ini` file for "mysql", hopefully it's in there but commented out.

Comment: I do not see any reference to mysql in this php.ini file. I do see this line of code however.                    extension_dir = ./